# PHP: Pass through file including mime-type

Tags: php

I would like to use `fpassthru` to relay files from another server.

The files are stored as static files on a webserver (thus the `MIME-type` is set correctly by `Apache`), but when I `fpassthru` then via `PHP`, they lose their `MIME-type`.

Basically what I would like to do is to relay the file as if it came from a static server (i.e. with the same headers or at least with the same MIME-type), **but I only want to use one connection to receive both data and MIME-type** for performance reasons.

How can I get the `MIME-type` of the file that I receive with `fpassthru` (or `file_get_contents` or another function)?

Comment: Have you checked if you can get the required info from [`$http_response_header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)? That variable should automatically get populated, when the HTTP Wrapper is involved - I don’t know at which specific point though. Guess you’d have to test it, if the relevant data is available directly after your `fopen` call (I’m assuming that’s what you are using), or if it would only get populated when you start reading data.

Comment: If you download it first you'll use one connection, cause you indeed don't need another connection for mime_content_type

Answer (score 1):

Get the MIME type with [`mime_content_type`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function, then set the `Content-Type` header using the [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, e.g.:

```php
<?php
$path = '/path/to/local/file.png';
$mime_type = mime_content_type($path) ?: 'application/octet-stream';
$file_size = filesize($path);

header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header("Content-Length: $file_size");
$fh = fopen($path, 'rb');
fpassthru($fh);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Your answer requires 3 connections to the remote server, which is too much - isn't there a way to only use one connection to download the data? After all the fpassthru function also receives the MIME-type from the server.

Comment: I have added a comment to make it clear in the question

Comment: @RolandSeuhs, do you mean that `$path` would be a URI pointing to a remove server? Then I would download the file to a temporary location before running `mime_content_type`, `file_size` and similar I/O functions. That was just an answer to your question. In regards to performance, I wouldn't use PHP for such kind of task at all. I'd rather configure a Web server such as nginx.